# Exception in file C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Layouts\EditingMenu\SiteAction.xml:

Tags: 2010

Anyone have an original siteaction.xml as the one we have is garbaged (corrupted) and has been replicated across the farm.  Or perhaps, do you know how to restore it from media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Console>
   <customfile FileName="CustomSiteAction" />
   <references>
       <reference TagPrefix="cms" 
         assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
         namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.EditingMenuActions" />
   </references>
   <structure >
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:CreateNewsLinkAction" 
         DisplayText="cms,siteactions_createnewslink_displaytext" 
         Description="cms,siteactions_createnewsLink_description"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="100" 
         Sequence="15" 
         PermissionContext="CurrentList" 
         HideIfDisabled="true" 
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/Actionscreate.gif"  
         ID="wsaCreateNewsLink"/>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:SiteDirectoryBrokenLinksCheckerAction"  
         DisplayText="cms,siteactions_brokenlinkschecker_displaytext"  
         Description="cms,siteactions_brokenlinkschecker_description"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="100"  
         Sequence="20"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
         HideIfDisabled="true"  
         ID="wsaBrknLinksScan"/>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:SwitchToAuthoringModeAction"  
         HideIfDisabled="true"  
         DisplayText="cms,siteactions_editpage_displaytext"  
         Description="cms,siteactions_editpage_description"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="100"  
         Sequence="50"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentItem"  
         ConfigMenu="Replace"  
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/ActionsEditPage.gif"  
         ID="wsaEditPage"  
         ChangedNodeID="MenuItem_EditPage" />
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:CreateNewPublishingPageAction"  
         HideIfDisabled="true"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="100"  
         Sequence="60"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentList"  
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/crtpage.gif"  
         UIVersion="3"
         ID="wsaCreatePage"/>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:CreateNewPublishingPageAction"  
         HideIfDisabled="true"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="200"  
         Sequence="210"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentList"  
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/crtpage.gif"  
         ID="wsaCreatePage"
         UIVersion="4"
         ConfigMenu="Replace"
         ChangedNodeID="MenuItem_CreatePage"/>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:CreateNewSiteAction"  
         DisplayText="cms,siteactions_createsite_displaytext"  
         Description="cms,siteactions_createsite_description"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/crtsite.gif"  
         MenuGroupId="100"  
         Sequence="70"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
         UIVersion="3"
         ID="wsaCreateSite"/>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:ReviewPublishingPageAction"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="100"  
         Sequence="80"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentItem"  
         HideStates="EditingMenuEnabled"  
         UIVersion="3"
         ID="wsaShowMenu"/>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:ReviewPublishingPageAction"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="100"  
         Sequence="80"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentItem"  
         HideStates="(EditingMenuEnabled)||(IsPublishingPageFalse)||(IsRibbonAlwaysShownTrue)"  
         UIVersion="4"
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/RibbonShowHH.png"  
         ID="wsaShowMenu"/>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:ExitMenuAction"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="100"  
         Sequence="90"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentItem"  
         HideStates="EditingMenuDisabled"  
         UIVersion="3"
         ID="wsaHideMenu"/>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:ExitMenuAction"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="100"  
         Sequence="90"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentItem"  
         HideStates="(EditingMenuDisabled)||(IsPublishingPageFalse)||(IsRibbonAlwaysShownTrue)"  
         UIVersion="4"
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/RibbonHideHH.png"  
         ID="wsaHideMenu"/>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:ViewAllSiteContentAction"  
         DisplayText="cms,siteactions_viewallsitecontent_displaytext"  
         Description="cms,siteactions_viewallsitecontent_description"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="200"  
         Sequence="150"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/vwcntnt.gif"  
         UIVersion="3"
         ID="wsaViewAllContent"  />
       <ConsoleNode
         ConfigMenu="Delete"  
         UIVersion="3"
         ChangedNodeID="MenuItem_Create"/>
       <ConsoleNode NodeClass="cms:ReportsNode"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="200"  
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/ViewReportsHH.png"  
         Sequence="175"  
         PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
         NavigateUrl="javascript:"  
         UserRights="EmptyMask"  
         UIVersion="3"
         ID="saShowReportsTP"/>
       <ConsoleNode 
         ConfigMenu="Delete"  
         UIVersion="3"
         ChangedNodeID="MenuItem_Settings"/>
       <ConsoleNode 
         DisplayText="cms,siteactions_sitesettingssubmenu_displaytext"  
         Description="cms,siteactions_sitesettingssubmenu_description"  
         UseResourceFile="true"   
         MenuGroupId="300"  
         Sequence="350"  
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/ActionsSettings.gif"
         UserRights="ManagePermissions|ManageWeb|ManageSubwebs|AddAndCustomizePages|ApplyThemeAndBorder|ManageAlerts|ManageLists|ViewUsageData"  
         RequiredRightsMode="Any"
         PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
         NavigateUrl="javascript:"  
         UIVersion="3"
         ID="SiteSettingsOptions">
           <ConsoleNode NavigateUrl="_layouts/settings.aspx"  
             DisplayText="cms,siteactions_modifysitesettings_displaytext"  
             Description="cms,siteactions_modifysitesettings_description"  
             UseResourceFile="true" 
             PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
             IsSiteRelative="true"  
             ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/ActionsSettings.gif"  
             ID="AllSiteSettings"  
             MenuGroupId="100"
             Sequence="50"
             UserRights="ManagePermissions|ManageWeb|ManageSubwebs|AddAndCustomizePages|ApplyThemeAndBorder|ManageAlerts|ManageLists|ViewUsageData"  
             RequiredRightsMode="Any"/>
           <ConsoleNode NavigateUrl="_layouts/people.aspx"  
             DisplayText="cms,siteactions_peopleandgroups_displaytext"
             Description="cms,siteactions_peopleandgroups_description"  
             UseResourceFile="true" 
             PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
             IsSiteRelative="true"  
             ID="PeopleAndGroup" 
             MenuGroupId="200"
             Sequence="125"
             UserRights="BrowseUserInfo"/>
           <ConsoleNode Action="cms:ModifyNavigationAction"  
             DisplayText="cms,siteactions_modifynavigation_displaytext" 
             Description="cms,siteactions_modifynavigation_description"  
             UseResourceFile="true"  
             PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
             MenuGroupId="200"
             Sequence="150"
             ID="wsaModifyNavigation"/>
           <ConsoleNode Action="cms:ModifyPagesLibrarySettingsAction"
             DisplayText="cms,siteactions_modifypageslibrarysettings_displaytext" 
             Description="cms,siteactions_modifypageslibrarysettings_description"  
             UseResourceFile="true"  
             PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
             ID="ModifyPagesLibrarySettings"
             MenuGroupId="200"
             Sequence="175"
             HideIfDisabled="true" 
             UserRights="EmptyMask"/>
       </ConsoleNode>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:ManageSiteAction"  
         DisplayText="cms,siteactions_managecontentandstructure_displaytext"  
         Description="cms,siteactions_managecontentandstructure_description"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="300"  
         Sequence="370"  
         UIVersion="3"
         PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/smt_small.png"  
         ID="wsaManageSite"/>
       <ConsoleNode Action="cms:ManageSiteAction"  
         DisplayText="cms,siteactions_managecontentandstructure_displaytext"  
         Description="cms,siteactions_managecontentandstructure_description"  
         UseResourceFile="true"  
         MenuGroupId="300"  
         Sequence="301"  
         UIVersion="4"
         PermissionContext="CurrentSite"  
         ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/smt_small.png"  
         ID="wsaManageSiteUIVersion4"/>
   </structure>
</Console>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastien that did the trick ... and now propogating to the farm.  :)